# Not able to grep a value from file using perl

Tags: perl

I need to grep a particular value from each line shown below:

```
ABC_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
```

From the above lines, I want to grep the values that has version numbers (`ABC04.16.103`, `DEF19.20.100`, `GHI19.10.199`, `JKL19.00.000`) and store these values in an array using Perl.

Comment: See [perl regex doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). `[A-Z]` matches all capital letters. `[A-Z]{3}` matches all capital letters 3 times. `\d`matches a single digit. `\.` matches a single `.`.

Comment: Welcome on the site. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far, and what errors have you encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while (<DATA>) {
        /([A-Z]{3}\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})/;
        print "$1\n";
    }

    __DATA__
    ABC_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
    DEF_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
    GHI_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
    JKL_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
```

Generates the following output:

```
ABC04.16.103
DEF19.20.100
GHI19.10.199
JKL19.00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do what you requested

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array;

map { m|/([^/]+)/lnx\d+| and push @array, $1 } <DATA>;

map { say } @array;

__DATA__
ABC_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/pulkit/pulkit_test/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
```

Output

```
ABC04.16.103
DEF19.20.100
GHI19.10.199
JKL19.00.000
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I am very new to Perl. Can you please let me know the way I can get the same values and store them in hash using Perl.